# How can a Spring controller forward error responses using WebClient without throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have a GET endpoint that makes a request to an external service using a WebClient.

`GET /myEndpoint` calls `PUT /externalEndpoint`.

`PUT /externalEndpoint` responds with a status code and an empty body on success, or a text (String) body when the status code is an error.

I'd like to set the status code of the response from `GET /myEndpoint` to be the same as the response from `PUT /externalEndpoint` (kind of like a partial response proxy). This is straightforward when the response from `PUT /externalEndpoint` is successful, but when it is a 403 error or similar. An exception is thrown and `GET /myEndpoint` returns a 500 status code and a large stack trace. An error response from `PUT /externalEndpoint` has no meaning outside of the myEndpoint context, so I'd like to handle resulting exceptions completely in the myEndpoint controller.

```java
@Value("${externalServiceBaseUrl}")
String externalServiceBaseUrl;

public ResponseEntity<String> myEndpoint() {
  final Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap();
  payload.put("example", "fake");

  final WebClient client = WebClient
    .builder()
    .baseUrl(externalServiceBaseUrl)
    .build()
  
  final ResponseEntity<String> response = client
    .put()
    .bodyValue(payload)
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(String.class)
    .block() // removing this is fine
    
  // somehow map response to a ResponseEntity<String> regardless of whether the client encountered an error response

}
```

Something like this is the goal:

```java
return ResponseEntity
  .status(response.getStatusCode())
  .headers(response.getHeaders())
  .body(response.getBody());
```

I've seen a lot of error-handling examples using the deprecated `.exchange` method, which would be nice to avoid. It would also be nice to avoid modifying the `client` (like with `.filter` methods) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just status code you could use `exchangeToMono` to implement custom request handler

```
Mono<HttpStatus> executeAntGetStatus() {
    return webClient.put()
            .uri("/externalEndpoint")
            .exchangeToMono(response ->
                    response.releaseBody()
                            .then(Mono.just(response.statusCode()))
    );
}
```

and then you could use it to `map` to result `ResponseEntity`

```
executeAntGetStatus(webClient)
        .map(status -> 
                ResponseEntity
                        .status(status)
                        ...
        );
```